# Django - Authentication credentials were not provided

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, google-chrome

I'm working with an endpoint that seems to be built on Django.

Attempting to setup basic aJax communication to it via POST I wrote:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://API-ENDPOINT-URL",
    data: "",
    dataType: "json",
    crossDomain: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Token <TOKEN THAT I WAS PROVIDED>' );
    },
    success: function(results)
    {
        reqListener(results)
    }


});
```

With those code a few things happened:

1. I first got a CORS error since I'm trying to build on my local server. I installed this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) to bypass it. (I have no access to the server to enable CORS)

2.I get this error in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://API-ENDPOINT-URL. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

3. looking at the Chrome console for the network request I see this comes back:

> {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}

What am I missing? Am I incorrectly sending the authentication token?

Comment: Which Django Authentication package are you using?

Comment: I can't tell. I don't have access to the sever, I'm just trying to interface with it from the client side in Javascript.

Comment: Can you try passing an extra option in ajax request `xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},`

Comment: @AgamBanga I tried that but still get the same response.

Answer (score 0):

Doing token auth via Javascript without CORS enabled is a suicide mission.

Do yourself a favor like I did and just do it via server side.